# Webpack using IgnorePlugin generates webpackMissingModule error

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to remove angular.js from my bundle. Couldn't find a way to remove it from the bundle.js because somehow Webpack resolves it from my entry file. So I decided to use `webpack.IgnorePlugin` but as a result I am recieving error .

> Cannot find module "angular"
>       at webpackMissingModule

I already included angular js from a cdn before bundle.js gets loaded. But it still tries to resolve it from webpack scripts.

webpack.make.js

```
module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig(options) {
    var config = {};
    config.entry = {
        app: './app/app.js'
    }
    config.output = {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        publicPath: BUILD ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'bundle.js',
    }
    ...
    config.module = {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw'
        }]
    };
    config.plugins = [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/angular$/),
    ];
    ...
    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Angular in your app, but don't want webpack to include it because it will come from somewhere else, you can set it as an external library and webpack won't load it.

It's a top level array config that specifies the libs you want to ignore in the bundle.

```
module.exports = {
  externals: ['angular']
}
```

You can then probably get rid of the ignore plugin and not have to deal with that extra part of the config.